# What is the name for noun phrases similar to "pound of flesh?"

Tags: parts-of-speech

In English, we commonly make noun phrases in the form "X of Y" where we're describing that "X" is comprised of "Y" - pound of flesh, sack of meat, lump of coal, and so on. I think I understand the individual parts of speech involved:

- "X" and "Y" are nouns or noun phrases
- "of" is a preposition describing the relationship between "X" and "Y"

...and the overall result ("X of Y") is itself a noun phrase. I'm curious if there's an exact name for this particular type of noun phrase. My research has consisted of searching those parts of speech, searching similar phrases, and browsing Wikipedia articles related to those parts of speech.

Comment: It's fitting that the tag you used is `parts of speech`.

Comment: I think "X of Y" represents too broad a category to address here. What do "Queen of England" and "pair of pants" and "lump of coal" and "pound of flesh" and "mark of Zorro" and "Toad of Toad Hall" have in common?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word you are seeking does not exist, it's just a noun phrase.